# Difference betwen logical disk and volume in windows OS?

Tags: windows, disk-volume

So what is the difference ?

If I use diskpart tool then they talking about volumes (list volume, select volume, ...).
But If I use WMI then there is win32_logicalDisk class.

Please explain, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is fairly simple, Microsoft does not have consistent terminology across their interfaces. The win32_logicalDisk WMI object is the same thing as a 'volume' in `diskpart`.

Comment: Plus, Microsoft likes to create new terminology when there are suitable others already in use.

Answer (score 2):

A logical disk can be comprised of multiple disk volumes using things like disk spanning or SAN volumes.  Logical is at the application level, Volume is at the HAL (give or take a little).

sysadmin's right, though.  There certainly is ambiguity in the terminology.